# How to build a custom view that will add its content to one of its children?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I have the following android layout, this code is duplicated across all activity layouts in my application:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/activity_actionbar_background"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/test_activity_content_frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <!-- content here -->

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I would like to refactor this layout into a view that can contain nested items and then be used in an activity layout like:

```
<com.my.app.ContentLayout>
    <!-- content here -->
</com.my.app.ContentLayout>
```

How would I develop my `ContentLayout` view class to achieve this?

Comment: But the content needs to be nested within the second FrameLayout, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refactor that layout in a custom component, you just need to take care of placing the content that you declare for `CustomLayout` in the inner `FrameLayout`(by overriding the default behavior of the `addView()` methods). Check the example below:

```
<!-- R.layout.Inner_content basic inner content that will be added to our custom component -->
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/dummy_id" <!-- we need an id that we could count on -->
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/activity_actionbar_background"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/test_activity_content_frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize">

        <!-- content here -->

    </FrameLayout>

</merge>
```

And the component itself will be:

```
public class CustomLayout extends RelativeLayout {

    private FrameLayout mContent;

    public CustomLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public CustomLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public CustomLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View content = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inner_content, this);
        mContent = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.test_activity_content_frame_layout);
    }

    @Override
    public void addView(View child) {
        if (isInnerContent(child)) {
            super.addView(child);
        } else {
            mContent.addView(child);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void addView(View child, int index) {
        if (isInnerContent(child)) {
            super.addView(child, index);
        } else {
            mContent.addView(child, index);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void addView(View child, int width, int height) {
        if (isInnerContent(child)) {
            super.addView(child, width, height);
        } else {
            mContent.addView(child, width, height);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void addView(View child, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        if (isInnerContent(child)) {
            super.addView(child, params);
        } else {
            mContent.addView(child, params);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void addView(View child, int index, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        if (isInnerContent(child)) {
            super.addView(child, index, params);
        } else {
            mContent.addView(child, index, params);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method will be used in the addView() methods of ContentLayout to add the children
     * to the proper container.
     *
     * @param newChild the new child view to test
     * @return false if the child should be added to the content FrameLayout,
     * for true add the child to the parent RelativeLayout
     */
    private boolean isInnerContent(View newChild) {
        if ((newChild instanceof FrameLayout) && (newChild.getId() == R.id.dummy_id ||
                newChild.getId() == R.id.test_activity_content_frame_layout)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks this is great! Could you edit the title of the question to make it clearer? I found it hard to word.

Comment: @S-K' I've edited the title but I don't know if this makes it better.